# MWE: Why are example-image-a.png and example-image-a.jpg of different size?

Tags: graphics, mwe

According to various tools the images `example-image-a.png` and `example-image-a.jpg` from the `mwe` package both have size 400 x 300 pixels. However, the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics{example-image-a.jpg}

\noindent
\includegraphics{example-image-a.png}
\end{document}
```

includes the pictures with different sizes. What determines the size at which the pictures are rendered, and why is it different in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The JPEG file `example-image-a.jpg` does have resolution information:

```
Image file name = example-image-a.jpg

* File [example-image-a.jpg]
( FP-DIV ) ( FP-DIV )
  Type: jpg
  Pixel width: 400 px
  Pixel height: 300 px
  Density x: 90 dots per 72.27pt
  Density y: 90 dots per 72.27pt
  Width: 319.99911 bp
  Height: 239.99905 bp
```

The `density` lines mean: **90 DPI**

The PNG file lacks information about resolution:

```
Image file name = example-image-a.png

* File [example-image-a.png]
( FP-DIV ) ( FP-MUL ) ( FP-DIV ) ( FP-DIV )
  Type: png
  Pixel width: 400 px
  Pixel height: 300 px
  Ratio x: 90
  Ratio y: 90
  Width: 399.99916 bp
  Height: 299.99965 bp
```

Therefore, a *default* resolution of **72 DPI** is used.

The data are extracted with:

```
pdftex bmpsize-test
```

## Setting of the default resolution

In case of pdfTeX, the *default* resolution can be set via `\pdfimageresolution`. This resolution is used, if pdfTeX cannot find resolution data in the bitmap file. The `graphics` driver file `pdftex.def` supports the setting of this resolution by option `resolution`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics{example-image-a.jpg}

\noindent
\includegraphics[resolution=90]{example-image-a.png}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Extracting resolution data (pdfTeX)

The resolution data can also be extracted from `example-image-a.jpg` and used for `example-image-a.png` via the help of package `bmpsize-base`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bmpsize-base}

\makeatletter
% Macro \SetMacroToImageResolution{#1}{#2}
% #1: macro that gets the rounded DPI integer value as result
% #2: image file with extension
% Result: Macro #1 is defined with the
%   rounded image resolution in DPI as integer
%   or 0 if the image is not found
%   or the resolution data are not complete.
\newcommand*{\SetMacroToImageResolutionX}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@ImageResolutionX\relax
    % Try the supported image formats for pdfTeX in PDF mode
    % until the correct image format is detected
    \@tfor\x:={jpg}{png}\do{%
      \expandafter\@TryGetImageResolutionX\expandafter{\x}{#2}%
      \ifx\@ImageResolutionX\relax
      \else
        \@break@tfor
      \fi
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand#1{\@ImageResolutionX}%
  }\x
}
\newcommand*{\@TryGetImageResolutionX}[2]{%
  \csname bmpsize@read@#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \ifbmpsize@ok % Image could be read
    \def\@ImageResolutionX{-1}%
    % Test for complete resolution data
    \ifx\bmpsize@unit\relax
    \else
      \ifx\bmpsize@pixelx\relax
      \else
         % Resolution data present
         \edef\x{\strip@pt\dimexpr\bmpsize@unit}%
         \FPset{\x}{\x}%
         \FPmul{\x}{\x}{\bmpsize@pixelx}%
         \FPdiv{\x}{\x}{72.27}%
         \FPround{\x}{\x}{0}%
         \let\@ImageResolutionX\x
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics{example-image-a.jpg}

\SetMacroToImageResolutionX\ImageResolution{example-image-a.jpg}

\noindent
\includegraphics[resolution=\ImageResolution]{example-image-a.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good to know that the graphics driver respects DPI metadata. I've actually encountered situations with files saved from the internet where the DPI ratio was corrupt or not present, causing the image to appear as a vertical or horizontal line in some viewers, so that's useful. (I ended up writing a small binary-editor script to fix that for JPEGs, but I seem to have lost it, oh well.)

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek is there a way to make it have the resolution of another graphic?

Comment: @MysticOdin See updated answer.